# Getting null point exception when an in app purchase is made

Tags: android, android-fragments, gradle

Upon testing with android.test.purchased the purchase is running good but when rolled to play store it crashes upon purchase completed.

Below is the code for on purchase completed.

This is crash stack:

java.lang.NullPointerException:

```
at android.widget.Toast.<init> (Toast.java:171)
  at android.widget.Toast.makeText (Toast.java:556)
  at android.widget.Toast.makeText (Toast.java:514)
  at com.py.reward.fragments.homefragment.onPurchasesUpdated (homefragment.java:321)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$1.onReceive (BillingClientImpl.java:136)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts (LocalBroadcastManager.java:303)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000 (LocalBroadcastManager.java:44)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage (LocalBroadcastManager.java:114)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7000)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:441)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)

    @Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase> purchases) {


    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK
            && purchases != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adddata();

        for (com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            ConsumeResponseListener listener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onConsumeResponse(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int responseCode, String outToken) {
                    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                        // Handle the success of the consume operation.
                        // For example, increase the number of coins inside the user's basket.
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Available for another purchase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            };

            mBillingClient.consumeAsync(purchase.getPurchaseToken(), listener);

        }
    } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
        // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.

    } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Purchase Limit Reached! Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else{

        // Handle any other error codes.
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item Available for another purchase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` `getActivity()` and `getContext()` probably null because you are using fragments !

Comment: Both the toasts are throwing errors